# How to implement eclipse editor into JavaFX UI

Tags: java, eclipse, webview, javafx, ace-editor

I currently have to code a code editor in `JavaFX`. I already tried using `Ace.js` using a `webview`, but I always get a `lowlevel sigsev` error in the `webview` natives. Now I wanted to implement the eclipse editor into the project, is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX) ?

Comment: @ItachiUchiha I already looked at it, but since I need to support a lot of languages it would be a huge effort to implement the syntax-highlighting

Comment: Ask the e(fx)clipse user forum and get in contact with Tom Schindl.  See: http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/TomSchindl/java-fx-xtext which discusses integration of JavaFX and xtext: https://eclipse.org/Xtext/